# How many flashpoints are there, and how are they gated

Tags: battletech

I'm playing battletech anew, because of the recent expansion.

Playing it from scratch, I saw that flashpoints are occurring right away.
And I'm a bit worried that this means I won't actually be able to complete flashpoints.

As such, do the flashpoints come back if not completed?
How many flashpoints are there in total?

Answer (score 2):

The flashpoints will spawn again.
There are 18 flashpoints, 13 general ones, which breaks down as *roughly* two per major faction, then there is one flashpoint that is opened up once you ally, again one per major faction.